# How to Convert all audio files in the same folder at the same time to another format

Tags: audio, format

I have one folder full of audio samples in mp3 format and i want to format all of them in OGG format. So to save time i want to format all at the same time. what method do you suggest?

Comment: anything media related always mention what OS you are on as things input/output related often have OS specific tools ...  ffmpeg will do this on any OS however you would need to write some code to put calls to ffmpeg into a loop which is easy enough to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an audio file converter utility may be the best option for you. One very good option is [NCH Switch](https://www.nch.com.au/switch/index.html). It's widely reviewed, and you get 30 days free use with no limitations. They allow you to *batch convert*, so you can add the whole folder, specify rename options (if you wish) and many other functions. It is quite simple and intuitive to use.
Another free and open source option is [fre:ac](https://www.freac.org/).

Comment: It might work, I have never used it. It also requires Linux